# Prove or disprove that exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that...

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n(x)= \frac{x}{n}e^{-x/n}, (0 \leq x < +\infty)$. And let $g_n(x)= \begin{cases} 
>        n & 0<x<\frac{1}{n} \\
>        0 & x \geq \frac{1}{n}          \end{cases}$
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> 1. Exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that $|f_n(x)-0| < \frac{1}{10}  (n \geq N)$ for all x simultaneously.
> 2. Exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that $|g_n(x) - 0| < \frac{1}{2}, (n \geq N)$ for all x simultaneously.

I know that the both functions converge pointwise to $0$. My first attempt was to look at the maximum of these functions, but I wasn't successful going this way.

Any hint or solutions would all be appreciated!

Comment: Finding the maximum of $1$ should have worked well.  If I give you $n$, what is the derivative?  What is the $x$ that makes the derivative be zero?  What is the value of the function at that $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that
$$
L_n  = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \geqslant 0} \left| {f_n \left( x \right) - 0} \right| \geqslant \left| {f_n \left( n \right)} \right| = e^{ - 1}  > \frac{1}
{{10}}
$$
therefore it **is not possible** to find an N such that if n> N 
$$
\left| {f_n \left( x \right) - 0} \right| \leqslant \frac{1}
{{10}}\,\,\,\,\,\forall x \geqslant 0
$$
You have also
$$
J_n  = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 0} \left| {g_n \left( x \right) - 0} \right| \geqslant \left| {g_n \left( {\frac{1}
{{2n}}} \right)} \right| = n > \frac{1}
{2}
$$
therefore it **is not possible** to find an N such that if n> N 
$$
\left| {g_n \left( x \right) - 0} \right| \leqslant \frac{1}
{{2}}\,\,\,\,\,\forall x > 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

By differentiation
$$\max_{x\in [0,\infty)} f_n(x)={1\over e}$$and $$\max_{x\in [0,\infty)}g_n(x)=n$$

Answer (score 1):

You get  a contradiction to 1) by putting $x=n$ and you get  a contradiction to 2) by putting $x=\frac 1 {2n}$.